# Does the Samkhya Darshana describe 24 tattva belonging only to human state or to all other conscious states?

Tags: philosophy, sankhya, shad-darshana

What would be the Tattva for the Sun or moon or say any star? If I was tree in the previous birth then from where the liking of the certain taste, things etc emerged in my childhood? If tanmatras are migrated or "*sesha*" which define the affinity and  karma of once new life, then what it would be for the conscious being other than human being or this form in which we are?